# Ajax request not working (asp.net-mvc)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

View:

```
@{
    AjaxOptions ajax = new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "sub_id" };
    Layout = null;       
}

<div id="sub_id"></div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajax))
{
    @Html.TextBox("email");
    <input type="submit" value="подписаться" />
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult LeftMenuSubscription(string email)
{
    return new ContentResult(){Content = "<script>alert('Thanks')</script>"};
}
```

"Thanks" alert show.

but in div `sub_id` set all page(`<title></title><div>...</div>`).

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

- connected.

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Главная страница</title>
        <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jQueryFixes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
        <form action="/" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#sub_id" id="form0" method="post">
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="подписаться">
        </form>
        ....
    </body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: *"but in div 'sub_id' set all page(...)."* what do you mean by this? What's the error/issue you're having?

Comment: IN "sub_id" should get <script>alert('Thanks')</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your Ajax options aren't complete. I believe you need to add the Action that you are requesting from:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", ajax))
{
    @Html.TextBox("email");
    <input type="submit" value="подписаться" />
}
```

Running this in a test I get a popup alert, which is exactly what should happen because you are returning a script that says: `<script>alert('Thanks')</script>`

If you just want the div to show `Thanks` then don't return the script tag

Use this if you just want to have the word thanks show up in the div

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult Test(string email) 
    return new ContentResult() { Content = "<span>Thanks</span>" };
}
```

This works perfect for me using the modified form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "Test", ajax))
{
    @Html.TextBox("email");
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```